# Send a image data url using ajax and save the file as png

Tags: java, javascript, image, servlets

I am trying to get the image from canvas and send the image as dataurl string to server 
and on server i want to save the dataurl as png image.
I have made something like this.

1>Upload code to send dataurl string to server.

```
function upload(){
    var url ="<%=request.getContextPath()%>/ImageSaver";
    xmlhttp = initialize();
    xmlhttp.open('POST',url,true);
    xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xmlhttp.send("imgdata="+img);
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange= function()
    {
        if(xmlhttp.readyState==4 && (xmlhttp.status==200 ||xmlhttp.status==404))    
        {
            alert("Image Uploaded Succesfully.");
            document.getElementById('img').src = img;
            if(xmlhttp.status==404 )
            {
                //  next.style.display="none";
            }
        }
        else
        {
            content.innerHTML = "Error";
        }   
    };
}
```

2> On server i am getting that dataurl and saving it as image.

```
try{
            String img64 = request.getParameter("imgdata");
            img64 = img64.replaceFirst("data:image/png;base64,","");
            byte[] decodedBytes = DatatypeConverter.parseBase64Binary(img64);
            System.out.println(""+img64);
            BufferedImage bfi = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(decodedBytes));    
            File outputfile = new File("D:/saved.png");
            ImageIO.write(bfi,"png",outputfile);
            bfi.flush();
         }
         catch(Exception e)
         {  
              e.printStackTrace();    
         }
```

But i am getting this error on server side

> javax.imageio.IIOException: Error reading PNG image data  at
>   com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.readImage(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.read(Unknown Source)
>     at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)   at
>   javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.tcs.ilp.t198.osms.prdm.controller.ImageSaver.doPost(ImageSaver.java:50)
>     at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)     at
>   javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)  at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
>     at
>   org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
>     at
>   org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
>     at
>   org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) Caused by:
>   java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid bit length repeat     at
>   java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)    at
>   com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodePass(Unknown Source)
>     at com.sun.imageio.plugins.png.PNGImageReader.decodeImage(Unknown
>   Source)   ... 20 more

Comment: Have you checked that your `decodedBytes` variable isn't `null`?

Comment: Yes, i have checked 'decodedBytes' variable is not null.